# What does 'fast friends' mean?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Does anyone have an idea? Close friends? I usually see this term in stories where the friends were best friends and then they fight for some reason.

Comment: `Usain Bolt` is fastest human (according to TIME mag) and if he is your friend then he is your fast[est] friend. :)

Comment: @Rakesh:then he would be fastest,I am searching for a 'fast friend'.

Comment: ah! my bad

Comment: *smiles.......!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fast):

> **fast**
>   [...]
>   **2** : firmly loyal <became *fast* friends>

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast#Adjective):

> Of people: steadfast, with unwavering feeling. (Now only in set phrases like "fast friend".) [from 10th c.]

Etymonline provides [some background](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=fast&searchmode=none):

> O.E. *fæst* "firmly fixed, steadfast, secure, enclosed," probably from P.Gmc. *fastuz (cf. O.Fris. *fest*, O.N. *fastr*, Du. *vast*, Ger. [*fest*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fest#German))

Comment: interetsing, i always thought "they became fast friends" meant "they quickly became friends"

Comment: @Claudiu: that would be "they became friends fast" or "they fast became friends". Note how you didn't write "they became quickly friends". An adverb doesn't really fit in there.

Comment: With the meaning of "firmly fixed", "fast" is also used in the phrase "stuck fast", to mean really, really stuck.

Comment: @Steve: and let us not forget "fasten your seatbelts".

Comment: I always thought that meant "make your seatbelts go faster!"

Comment: @Steve And _fast asleep_, of course.

Answer (score 7):

The sense of "fast" here is almost obsolete; it's the "fast" of "steadfast," as noted by RegDwight above. It means "tight" or "secure," and you'll see it in literature in expressions like "hold fast" meaning to "get a tight grip" (on something). "Hold fast to your dreams" means to keep them close and never let them go.

Which is exactly what you should do with a good friend.

Answer (score -3):

Fast friends are people who newly meet by circumstances but find themselves mutually trustworthy and so, bond together.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This site expects references to back up your assertions. For a good answer, see the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4582/91730) on this question, which has a dictionary reference to back it up.

Answer (score -3):

Fast friends means friends who spend most of their time in a day together. Or friends who are always seen together.

Answer (score -6):

A pairing of two or more people whom quickly become close and find each other disposable; similar to fast food : readily available and enjoyable at the time.

Comment: That is not what _fast_ means here. Your use of _whom_ is also incorrect.